# Feedback on a code on "Split the array so that the sum of the numbers on one side is equal to the sum of the numbers on the other side."

Tags: java, arrays

Problem: Given a non-empty array, return true if there is a place to split the array so that the sum of the numbers on one side is equal to the sum of the numbers on the other side.

For the given problem, does my code run for worst cases?
I saw other solutions, but I want feedback on my code.

```
canBalance([1, 1, 1, 2, 1]) → true
canBalance([2, 1, 1, 2, 1]) → false
canBalance([10, 10]) → true
```

My Code:

```
public boolean canBalance(int[] nums) {
    int n = nums.length;
    int mid = n/2;

    if(n == 2)
        mid = mid - 1;

    int sum = 0;
    int sum1 = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<=mid; i++)
        sum+=nums[i];

    for(int i = mid+1; i<n; i++)
        sum1+=nums[i];

    int r;
    if(sum1>sum)
        r = sum1 - sum;
    else
        r = sum - sum1;

    if(r == 2 || r == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I think you want a code review of code without known failures, instead of asking a question on a programming problem.

Comment: in loops , `i<mid` and `i=mid`

Comment: You are currently checking only one position to be applicable for the split. For `[1, 1, 1, 2, 5]` your method returns `false`.

Comment: Sum all the numbers first. If the sum is odd, you know it can't be split evenly, so return false. It it's even, start summing from the start again. If you can reach exactly half the sum, return true. As soon as you exceed half the sum, return false. This is O(n).

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I was thinking about approaching the list from both sides, advancing the side that is smaller and seeing if they "meet in the middle," but your solution is a lot cleaner and easier to implement.

Comment: Thank you so much :)
I am new to here. I will keep all these in my mind :)

Comment: @Torben that would be a good way to do it, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is only checking from the mid point, and it is taking `O(2n)`. What if there is other position that gives the same result.

This one looks any position and takes `O(n)`
it works like this: We have the left array `leftNums` holds cumulative sum at each index from start end where as the right array `rightNums`  holds cumulative sum at each index starting from the last end.
finally we compare sums from these arrays to check if sum are equal at any position.

```
public static boolean canBalance(int[] nums) {
    int sumRight=0;
    int sumLeft=0;
    int[] leftNums = new int[nums.length];
    int[] rightNums = new int[nums.length];
    for (int i=0; i < nums.length;i++){
        sumLeft= sumLeft+nums[i];
        sumRight=sumRight+nums[nums.length-i-1];
        leftNums[i]=sumLeft;
        rightNums[nums.length-i-1]=sumRight;        
  }  
  for(int j=0;j < nums.length -1;j++){
    if(leftNums[j] == rightNums[j+1]) 
        return true;
  }
  return false;
}
}
```

Comment: The current solution takes `O(2n)`, which is equivalent to `O(n)`. There are two loops, but they are not nested, hence none of them is entering more than once. Otherwise this solution works, though there even is one with `O(n)`. ;)

Comment: @Izruo right, but what if there is other position(other than mid point) that gives the same result?

Comment: This solution throws java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because of the following command: sumRight=sumRight+ nums[j];

Comment: @dbl the arrays have to have the same length, may be you are using arrays with different length

Comment: Since it isn't obvious for you I will explain further more. You have two cycles where the first one is iterating through *0 to N* and then the second one is iterating trough *m to N+1* where *N is the max index in the array*. It will be aways the case where you haven't returned trough to try access array[max index + 1]...

Comment: @dbl what about now, i made changes to loop 2.

Comment: You have fixed the issue. Now it works as expected but still this is not covering what's been asked to do.

Comment: @SamsrutiDash check now, i have updated the code and it takes `O(n)`.

Comment: @dbl  can you check now, I have updated the code and it takes only O(n)

Comment: I got the reference now thanks :) @everyone
This community will be my first love always :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is my feedback. First of all your solution is not working as expected. Your solution is covering only 1 special case but non of the others. It will print wrong output for most of the cases like those:

```
{3, 1, 1, 1} -> false
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6} -> false
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 10} -> false
{6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} -> false
```

You are splitting the array at two equal parts (by size, not by value) then you are are first summing all the left hand members, then all the right hand members and then you expect the sums to be equal...

Since this is quite a simple task and indeed the solution should be intuitive to most people I will try to explain my logic behind this.

You have to find if the array could be splitted on two equal by value parts and the elements inside should keep their current order(this makes task super simple). Instead of starting from the mid you should start summing both sides from the boarders. *lefthandSum* and *rightHandSum* should keep staying balanced. While the leftSum is less than the rightSum only add next most left number to the leftSum. If the case is where the leftSum is greater than the rightSum then only add the most right number to the rightSum. If both the sums are equal do add both the most left to the leftSum and the mostRight to the rightSum. Do that until the two indexes meet. Here is some code and then examples.

```
public boolean canBalance(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    int leftSum = 0;
    int rightSum = 0;
    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = arr.length - 1;

    while (leftIndex <= rightIndex) {
        if (leftSum == rightSum) {
            if (leftIndex == rightIndex) {
                return false;
            }
            leftSum += arr[ leftIndex++ ];
            rightSum += arr[ rightIndex-- ];
        } else if (leftSum < rightSum) {
            leftSum += arr[ leftIndex++ ];
        } else {
            rightSum += arr[ rightIndex-- ];
        }
    }
    return leftSum == rightSum;
}
```

And here are how the iterations will go(by adding some printlines).

Test with input arrays :

> {3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 21};
>
> {3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 21, 8};
>
> {3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 9, 21, 8};

Test with {3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 21};

> i[0] : left = 0, {<- 3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 21 ->}, 0 = right
> i[1] : left = 3, {3, <- 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 21}, 21 = right
> i[2] : left = 4, {3, 1, <- 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 21}, 21 = right
> i[3] : left = 8, {3, 1, 4, <- 7, 2, 5, 7, 21}, 21 = right
> i[4] : left = 15, {3, 1, 4, 7, <- 2, 5, 7, 21}, 21 = right
> i[5] : left = 17, {3, 1, 4, 7, 2, <- 5, 7, 21}, 21 = right
> i[6] : left = 22, {3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7 ->, 21}, 21 = right
> i[7] : left = 22, {3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5 ->, <- 7, 21}, 28 = right
> left ?= right : 22 == 28 : FALSE!

```
Input array is [3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 21]
Let leftSum = 0.
Let rightSum = 0.
Let leftIndex = 0.
Let rightIndex = arr.length - 1, [ 7 ].
While leftIndex [ 0 ] <= rightIndex [ 7 ], do :
leftSum [ 0 ] is equal to rightSum [ 0 ], add next most left number to the leftSum and next most right number to the rightSum.
Adding arr [0] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 3 .
Adding arr [7] to the rightSum. rightSum is now equal to 21 .
While leftIndex [ 1 ] <= rightIndex [ 6 ], do :
leftSum [ 3 ] is less than rightSum [ 21 ], add next most LEFT number to the leftSum and keep the rightSum as it is.
Adding arr [1] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 4 .
While leftIndex [ 2 ] <= rightIndex [ 6 ], do :
leftSum [ 4 ] is less than rightSum [ 21 ], add next most LEFT number to the leftSum and keep the rightSum as it is.
Adding arr [2] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 8 .
While leftIndex [ 3 ] <= rightIndex [ 6 ], do :
leftSum [ 8 ] is less than rightSum [ 21 ], add next most LEFT number to the leftSum and keep the rightSum as it is.
Adding arr [3] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 15 .
While leftIndex [ 4 ] <= rightIndex [ 6 ], do :
leftSum [ 15 ] is less than rightSum [ 21 ], add next most LEFT number to the leftSum and keep the rightSum as it is.
Adding arr [4] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 17 .
While leftIndex [ 5 ] <= rightIndex [ 6 ], do :
leftSum [ 17 ] is less than rightSum [ 21 ], add next most LEFT number to the leftSum and keep the rightSum as it is.
Adding arr [5] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 22 .
While leftIndex [ 6 ] <= rightIndex [ 6 ], do :
leftSum [ 22 ] is greater than rightSum [ 21 ], add next most RIGHT number to the rightSum and keep the leftSum as it is.
Adding arr [6] to the rightSum. rightSum is now equal to 28 .
leftIndex [ 6 ] > rightIndex [ 5 ], exit!
Return : leftSum [ 22 ] ?= rightSum [28], = false
Result from canBalance is : FALSE
```

Test with {3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 21, 8};

> i[0] : left = 0, {<- 3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 21, 8 ->}, 0 = right
> i[1] : left = 3, {3, <- 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 21, 8}, 8 = right
> i[2] : left = 4, {3, 1, <- 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 21, 8}, 8 = right
> i[3] : left = 8, {3, 1, 4, <- 7, 2, 5, 7, 21 ->, 8}, 8 = right
> i[4] : left = 15, {3, 1, 4, 7, <- 2, 5, 7, 21, 8}, 29 = right
> i[5] : left = 17, {3, 1, 4, 7, 2, <- 5, 7, 21, 8}, 29 = right
> i[6] : left = 22, {3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, <- 7, 21, 8}, 29 = right
> i[7] : left = 29, {3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7 ->, <- 21, 8}, 29 = right
> left ?= right : 29 == 29 : TRUE!

```
Input array is [3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 21, 8]
Let leftSum = 0.
Let rightSum = 0.
Let leftIndex = 0.
Let rightIndex = arr.length - 1, [ 8 ].
While leftIndex [ 0 ] <= rightIndex [ 8 ], do :
leftSum [ 0 ] is equal to rightSum [ 0 ], add next most left number to the leftSum and next most right number to the rightSum.
Adding arr [0] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 3 .
Adding arr [8] to the rightSum. rightSum is now equal to 8 .
While leftIndex [ 1 ] <= rightIndex [ 7 ], do :
leftSum [ 3 ] is less than rightSum [ 8 ], add next most LEFT number to the leftSum and keep the rightSum as it is.
Adding arr [1] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 4 .
While leftIndex [ 2 ] <= rightIndex [ 7 ], do :
leftSum [ 4 ] is less than rightSum [ 8 ], add next most LEFT number to the leftSum and keep the rightSum as it is.
Adding arr [2] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 8 .
While leftIndex [ 3 ] <= rightIndex [ 7 ], do :
leftSum [ 8 ] is equal to rightSum [ 8 ], add next most left number to the leftSum and next most right number to the rightSum.
Adding arr [3] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 15 .
Adding arr [7] to the rightSum. rightSum is now equal to 29 .
While leftIndex [ 4 ] <= rightIndex [ 6 ], do :
leftSum [ 15 ] is less than rightSum [ 29 ], add next most LEFT number to the leftSum and keep the rightSum as it is.
Adding arr [4] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 17 .
While leftIndex [ 5 ] <= rightIndex [ 6 ], do :
leftSum [ 17 ] is less than rightSum [ 29 ], add next most LEFT number to the leftSum and keep the rightSum as it is.
Adding arr [5] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 22 .
While leftIndex [ 6 ] <= rightIndex [ 6 ], do :
leftSum [ 22 ] is less than rightSum [ 29 ], add next most LEFT number to the leftSum and keep the rightSum as it is.
Adding arr [6] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 29 .
leftIndex [ 7 ] > rightIndex [ 6 ], exit!
Return : leftSum [ 29 ] ?= rightSum [29], = true
Result from canBalance is : TRUE
```

Test with {3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 9, 21, 8};

> i[0] : left = 0, {<- 3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 9, 21, 8 ->}, 0 = right
> i[1] : left = 3, {3, <- 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 9, 21, 8}, 8 = right
> i[2] : left = 4, {3, 1, <- 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 9, 21, 8}, 8 = right
> i[3] : left = 8, {3, 1, 4, <- 7, 2, 5, 7, 9, 21 ->, 8}, 8 = right
> i[4] : left = 15, {3, 1, 4, 7, <- 2, 5, 7, 9, 21, 8}, 29 = right
> i[5] : left = 17, {3, 1, 4, 7, 2, <- 5, 7, 9, 21, 8}, 29 = right
> i[6] : left = 22, {3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, <- 7, 9, 21, 8}, 29 = right
> i[7] : left = 29, {3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7 , -> 9 <-, 21, 8}, 29 = right
> leftIndex == rightIndex && left == right : 29 == 29 : remaining number is 9! FALSE!

```
Input array is [3, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 7, 9, 21, 8]
Let leftSum = 0.
Let rightSum = 0.
Let leftIndex = 0.
Let rightIndex = arr.length - 1, [ 9 ].
While leftIndex [ 0 ] <= rightIndex [ 9 ], do :
leftSum [ 0 ] is equal to rightSum [ 0 ], add next most left number to the leftSum and next most right number to the rightSum.
Adding arr [0] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 3 .
Adding arr [9] to the rightSum. rightSum is now equal to 8 .
While leftIndex [ 1 ] <= rightIndex [ 8 ], do :
leftSum [ 3 ] is less than rightSum [ 8 ], add next most LEFT number to the leftSum and keep the rightSum as it is.
Adding arr [1] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 4 .
While leftIndex [ 2 ] <= rightIndex [ 8 ], do :
leftSum [ 4 ] is less than rightSum [ 8 ], add next most LEFT number to the leftSum and keep the rightSum as it is.
Adding arr [2] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 8 .
While leftIndex [ 3 ] <= rightIndex [ 8 ], do :
leftSum [ 8 ] is equal to rightSum [ 8 ], add next most left number to the leftSum and next most right number to the rightSum.
Adding arr [3] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 15 .
Adding arr [8] to the rightSum. rightSum is now equal to 29 .
While leftIndex [ 4 ] <= rightIndex [ 7 ], do :
leftSum [ 15 ] is less than rightSum [ 29 ], add next most LEFT number to the leftSum and keep the rightSum as it is.
Adding arr [4] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 17 .
While leftIndex [ 5 ] <= rightIndex [ 7 ], do :
leftSum [ 17 ] is less than rightSum [ 29 ], add next most LEFT number to the leftSum and keep the rightSum as it is.
Adding arr [5] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 22 .
While leftIndex [ 6 ] <= rightIndex [ 7 ], do :
leftSum [ 22 ] is less than rightSum [ 29 ], add next most LEFT number to the leftSum and keep the rightSum as it is.
Adding arr [6] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to 29 .
While leftIndex [ 7 ] <= rightIndex [ 7 ], do :
leftSum [ 29 ] is equal to rightSum [ 29 ], add next most left number to the leftSum and next most right number to the rightSum.
Since we can not add arr[ 7 ] to both the sums and we either add it to one of them then it will be greater than the other! Returning false!!!
Result from canBalance is : FALSE
```

And then code modifications added in order to get the printed output are:

```
public boolean canBalance(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println("Input array is " + Arrays.toString(arr));

    System.out.println("Let leftSum = 0.");
    System.out.println("Let rightSum = 0.");
    System.out.println("Let leftIndex = 0.");
    System.out.println("Let rightIndex = arr.length - 1, [ " + (arr.length - 1) + " ].");

    int leftSum = 0;
    int rightSum = 0;
    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = arr.length - 1;

    while (leftIndex <= rightIndex) {
        System.out.println("While leftIndex [ " + leftIndex + " ] <= rightIndex [ " + rightIndex + " ], do :");

        if (leftSum == rightSum) {
            System.out.println("leftSum [ " + leftSum + " ] is equal to rightSum [ " + rightSum + " ], add next most left number to the leftSum and next most right number to the rightSum.");

            if (leftIndex == rightIndex) {
                System.out.println("Since we can not add arr[ " + leftIndex + " ] to both the sums and we either add it to one of them then it will be greater than the other! Returning false!!!");
                return false;
            }

            System.out.print("Adding arr [" + leftIndex + "] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to ");
            leftSum += arr[ leftIndex++ ];
            System.out.println(leftSum + " .");

            System.out.print("Adding arr [" + rightIndex + "] to the rightSum. rightSum is now equal to ");
            rightSum += arr[ rightIndex-- ];
            System.out.println(rightSum + " .");

        } else if (leftSum < rightSum) {
            System.out.println("leftSum [ " + leftSum + " ] is less than rightSum [ " + rightSum + " ], add next most LEFT number to the leftSum and keep the rightSum as it is.");

            System.out.print("Adding arr [" + leftIndex + "] to the leftSum. leftSum is now equal to ");
            leftSum += arr[ leftIndex++ ];
            System.out.println(leftSum + " .");
        } else {
            System.out.println("leftSum [ " + leftSum + " ] is greater than rightSum [ " + rightSum + " ], add next most RIGHT number to the rightSum and keep the leftSum as it is.");

            System.out.print("Adding arr [" + rightIndex + "] to the rightSum. rightSum is now equal to ");
            rightSum += arr[ rightIndex-- ];
            System.out.println(rightSum + " .");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("leftIndex [ " + leftIndex + " ] > rightIndex [ " + rightIndex + " ], exit!");

    System.out.println("Return : leftSum [ " + leftSum + " ] ?= rightSum [" + rightSum + "], = " + (leftSum == rightSum));
    return leftSum == rightSum;
}
```